# SQL query for getting data for last 3 months

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, select

How can you get today's date and convert it to `01/mm /yyyy` format and get data from the table with delivery month 3 months ago? Table already contains delivery month as `01/mm/yyyy`.

Comment: `WHERE Convert(DATE,TableColumn)>= GETDATE()-90`?? Did you try anything so far?

Comment: Why are you storing a date as a character string?  You should fix the table.

Comment: The month is created in the table from the delivery date in the format 01/mm/yyyy. This is so as for the ease of use later for php. So in order to get specific type of delivery for the last 3 months I was thinking to get today's date and convert it to 01/mm/yyyy format and ref it with the delivery month in the table to get least 3 month including current month data.

Comment: I tried to select top3 and order it by delivery month description but it have me the top 3 delivery for the month. So I used

Comment: Datepart (mm, get date)

Comment: But ended up with the problem last 3 months should have Dec of last year. It wasn't giving me Dec of last year

Comment: I just up-voted this question, I can't understand why people has down-voted this question. This is really helpful for me.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE Date_Column >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
```

Mureinik's suggested method will return the same results, but doing it this way your query can benefit from any indexes on `Date_Column`.

or you can check against last 90 days.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE Date_Column >= DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Actually you can do `GETDATE()-90` instead `DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE()) `

Comment: @huMptyduMpty But 3 months is not necessarily 90 days, because months may have 30 or 31 days (or even 28 or 29 if we take February into account)

Comment: Will this work if I have a date time variable? DateTIME_Column >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())

Comment: DATEADD not supported anymore, see comments below.

Answer (score 19):

Latest Versions of mysql don't support DATEADD instead use the syntax

```
DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type)
```

To get the last 3 months data use,

```
DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -90 DAY) 
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH)
```

Comment: `DATE_ADD` worked perfectly! `DATEADD` seems not to exist in MySQL.

Answer (score 9):

I'd use `datediff`, and not care about format conversions:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  DATEDIFF(MONTH, my_date_column, GETDATE()) <= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Last 3 months

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,DATEADD(mm,-3,GETDATE())),0)
```

Today

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Last 3  months record

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(NOW(),`created_at`)as Datediff from `transactions` as t having Datediff <= 90
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *  FROM tasks WHERE  task_date_creation > date_sub(now(),Interval 3 month)