# MySQL query for at least once in x days

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is like this:

Name: User Transaction Data
Date format DD/MM/YYYY
Data of only 4 months (Sept,Oct,Nov,Dec)

```
Id   User  Date
25   127   23/10/2014 
26   128   25/11/2014 
25   127   22/11/2014
47   17    22/1/2014
25   127   12/9/2014
25   127   22/12/2014
```

If I want to find user whose entry is present at least once in 30 days.
The answer should be 127. As user 127 is present in all 4 months at least once
User 128 done only one transaction in Nov. Not done transaction at least once in every month so not selected

How to write a query for this?

Comment: What does the `Id` column mean? Obviously, it is not a primary key.

Comment: ID 25 and corresponding entry for user127 is present in every month

Comment: So you want to query all user ids which have an entry for every month until today? But counting from which date?

Comment: Please provide a name for your table (it is a very common mistake that people make here, though it continues to surprise me).  You also need to explain more clearly what you are after.  For example,  if there was an entry (35, 27, 22/10/2014), would that qualify to be selected?  What about (35, 27, 21/10/2014)?  What entries would be required so that user 27 could be selected?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler modified table!  To make 35 to qualify he should at least do 1 transaction in month.

Comment: @Strawberry for easy we can take each months 30 days ! Other way can be each 30 days in past from today (21st Nov to 21st Dec)

Comment: Mahesh, I think you really need to think a little more carefully about what it is you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE Date_Column >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE Date_Column >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21912827

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT User, COUNT(*) AS number_of_presence FROM (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`Date`,'%Y-%m') AS date_month, User    
  FROM `table`

  GROUP BY date_month, User 
) TMP 
GROUP BY User
HAVING number_of_presence = 4
```

The `group by` is used to avoid same user multiple times.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/226a24/1)

Comment: Not working ! can you explain what needs to be done for date ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after *any consecutive 30 days*, right?
Unfortunately you probably have to join the table to itself, as it looks for *pairs* of rows. Then the query would be:

```
select
  a1.User,
  a1.Date as fromDate,
  a2.Date as toDate,
  datediff(a1.Date, a2.Date) as span
from appearances a1, appearances a2
where
  a1.User=a2.User and
  a2.Date>a1.Date and
  datediff(a2.Date, a1.Date) <= 30;
```

Creating the structure for the record:

```
CREATE TABLE appearances
    (`Id` int, `User` int, `Date` date)
;

INSERT INTO appearances
    (`Id`, `User`, `Date`)
VALUES
    (25, 127, '2014-10-23'),
    (26, 128, '2014-11-25'),
    (25, 127, '2014-11-22'),
    (47, 17, '2014-01-22'),
    (25, 127, '2014-09-12'),
    (25, 127, '2014-12-22')
;
```

fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a3363/7/0

Answer (score 0):

If you know the dates you want to check for a user to be present, you can select all rows `WHERE` the date is within your range. I would use the `BETWEEN` keyword. For example, if you want users who were active in the month of march, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN '2014-03-01' AND '2014-03-31';
```

For this specific example, it seems like you want users who have made at least one purchase in each of the last 4 months. What you can do is use start by getting the rows for each of the last 4 months by using the `DATE_SUB()` function to set the start date:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH);
```

Once you have that, you can add a `GROUP BY` statement to group by user and month to get one row per user and month:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH)
GROUP BY user, MONTH(date);
```

Once you have that, you can pull from it the the users `HAVING` four rows because it means they've made a purchase in each of the four months:

```
SELECT user
FROM(
  SELECT *
  FROM myTable
  WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH)
  GROUP BY user, MONTH(date)) t
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(*) = 4;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6324d/6) example.

Also, here are some good date and time [functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for you to keep in mind.