# How to get last 3 month on selection of any month and year

Tags: sql-server-2008

Kindly help me to solve the query:

- How to get last 3 month on selection of any month ?

I need last 3 month on selection of any month

e.g:  if I select **July** 2015 , then I need months  **06,05,04**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912173/sql-query-for-getting-data-for-last-3-months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--set @Input_Date as 07-01-2015 for July 2015

Declare @Input_Date Date

    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE cast(Date_Column as date) >= cast(DATEADD(MONTH, -3,@Input_Date) as date)   and  cast(Date_Column as date) <=@Input_Date

    --cast to date is purposely done to avoid comparision issues for time part
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE Date_Column >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
```

Comment: but i need to pass month digit only

Comment: @Anurag..and then what about year??