# SELECT records FROM amount_history WHERE amount1 is l<= max amount2 in last 3 years

Tags: sql, oracle

I know basic SQL but am trying to come up with a query that is beyond me.

AMOUNT_HISTORY table is something like this

[image]

I can add an input parameter for effective date, say effectiveDate.

The highest Amount1 for RefNo 1 in last 3 years is 12,000 which is the <= the Amount2 at the effectiveDate - thats fine.

The highest Amount1 for RefNo 2 in last 3 years is 22,000, which is > than the Amount2 at the effective Date - I need to select the RefNo in that case.

Note the dates go back further, so will need the last 3 dates criteria. There will only be dates on the anniversary of the effectiveDate. Normally I would add the query I have developed thus far, but I didn't get further than a simple Select From Where so not much progress made really. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the desired output? Just the RefNo whenever the max Amount1 over the last 3 years is greater than the Amount2 on the effective date? Or more info about RefNo? (Perhaps all three rows for that RefNo, three years back from the effective date?) Also, three years back should include year 2014 also, or not?

Comment: Output required is refno, amount2 whenever the max amount1 over the last 3 years is greater than the amount2 on the effective date. 3 years back from an effective date of 1/1/17 should include 2017, 2016 and 2015. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to select only the rows where the date is between "effective date minus two years" and "effective date". This is done best in the `WHERE` clause, with a `between` condition, using `add_months()` to subtract two years from the effective date. Note - I used `dt` as column name (**`date`** is reserved in Oracle and shouldn't be used as an identifier); and I pass the effective date as a bind variable.

Then, from the remaining rows, group by `refno`, and compare `max(amount1)` to the `amount2` on the effective date. This is a comparison at the group level, not at the individual row level, so it goes in the `HAVING` clause, not in the `WHERE` clause.

Lastly, `amount2` on the effective date is at the row level, not at the group level; so we need a little trick. I use a "conditional maximum" - the `max()` function applied to an expression that is `amount2` when the date is the effective date, but `null` on the other dates. A `case` expression is perfect for that.

```
with
     test_data ( refno, dt, amount1, amount2 ) as (
       select 1, date '2017-01-01', 12000, 12000 from dual union all
       select 1, date '2016-01-01', 11000, null  from dual union all
       select 1, date '2015-01-01', 10500, null  from dual union all
       select 2, date '2017-01-01', 20000, 10000 from dual union all
       select 2, date '2016-01-01', 21000, null  from dual union all
       select 2, date '2015-01-01', 22000, null  from dual       
     )
--  End of test data (not part of the solution). SQL query begins below this line.
select   refno, max(case when dt = :effective_date then amount2 end) as amount2
from     test_data
where    dt between add_months(:effective_date, -24) and :efffective_date
group by refno
having   max(amount1) > max(case when dt = :effective_date then amount2 end)
;

REFNO  AMOUNT2
-----  -------
    2    10000
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't provide you the direct answer but definitely will help you getting the correct answer.

So, basically you need to learn - 
GROUP BY along with aggregate function - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp.

Group by clause group the results by ref no and then use aggregate function MAX

DATE_ADD - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp
[sql query for getting data for last 3 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912173/sql-query-for-getting-data-for-last-3-months)

Use DATE_ADD to add the criteria for interval of last 3 years

Comment: Please try providing complete solution instead of just providing hints or pointers. I'm not the downvoter!

Comment: There is no `date_add()` in Oracle