# How to fetch only first 4 months of data from past 3 years via SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to fetch the first 4 months of data in the past 3 years with a SQL query. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Please include the DDL, sample data and expected output by editing your question and all should be in text format. Better if you will provide like SQL script create table, insert table and also include what you have tried.

Comment: @SurajKumar My question is a little similar to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912173/sql-query-for-getting-data-for-last-3-months/21912827). Just that I have past 3 years of data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DATE_ADD()` function with `month` and `year`  *datepart* arguments

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tab 
 WHERE CAST( date_inserted  AS DATE)
       BETWEEN CAST( DATEADD(year, -3, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
           AND CAST( DATEADD(month, 4, DATEADD(year, -3, GETDATE())) AS DATE)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f7f82666ee46c78873a5dd3c7a4959f2)</kbd>

where `GETDATE()` represents the current timestamp value of the DBMS