# I want the latest 3 months orders

Tags: mysql

I want the latest 3 months of orders where I have two tables

1. Orders Table

```
CREATE TABLE `Orders` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `OrderID` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `shopId` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `customerId` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `itemCount` int NOT NULL,
  `totalPrice` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
  `customerEmail` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `totalWeightInGrams` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `shopDomain` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

2. OrderItems Table

```
 CREATE TABLE `OrderItems` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `orderId` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `variantId` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `shopDomain` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(13,4) NOT NULL,
  `weightInGrams` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount` decimal(13,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `requiresShipping` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I want to get the recent 3 months orders. actually There are two types of orders.
I want to differentiate the orders by title there would be one product will be added in the orders which I need to check the orders with that products and without products.
Insert demo data.

```
    INSERT INTO `Orders` (`id`, `OrderID`, `shopId`, `customerId`, `itemCount`, `totalPrice`, `customerEmail`, `totalWeightInGrams`, `shopDomain`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`) VALUES
(1, '4029121691694', '1', '5376382468142', 2, '44.36', 'shiv@test.com', '2000.0000', 'test.com', '2021-12-01 14:02:24', '2021-12-01 14:02:24'),
(7, '4029152722990', '1', '5376382468142', 2, '44.36', 'shiv@one.com', '2000.0000', 'test2.com',  '2021-12-01 15:01:16', '2021-12-01 15:01:16'),



INSERT INTO `OrderItems` (`id`, `orderId`, `variantId`, `title`, `quantity`, `sku`, `shopDomain`, `price`, `weightInGrams`, `discount`, `currency`, `requiresShipping`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`) VALUES
(5, '4029121691694', '32790648258606', ' product test1 ', 1, 'ST-0001', 'test.com', '19.9900', 2000, '0.00', 'INR', 1, '2021-12-01 14:02:25', '2021-12-01 14:02:25'),
(6, '4029121691694', '39639081451566', 'Static product', 1, 'STO2020', 'test.com', '0.6500', 0, '0.00', 'INR', 0, '2021-11-17 14:02:25', '2021-12-01 14:02:25'),
(7, '4029152722990', '39639081451566', 'Static product', 1, 'STO2020', 'test.com', '0.6500', 0, '0.00', 'INR', 0, '2021-12-01 15:01:17', '2021-12-01 15:01:17');
```

I am adding static product in the order so I need to check the all orders which have "static product" title and without static products with recent 3 month orders.

Output will be something like this, it is not exactly output for this data query but it could be something similar according to data.

```
"orders": {
"2021-11-01": {
  "total": 1,
  "staticProductOrder": 1
},
"2021-12-01": {
  "total": 3,
  "staticProductOrder": 2
}
```

}

I have execute this query

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN OrderItems on Orders.OrderId = OrderItems.orderId 
where Orders.shopDomain = '${Domain}'
```

I have got all the orders.

Please can someone help me in that.
if you have any issue please let me know.

Comment: Add the condition by the date (the date must be not less than current one minus 3 months). PS. MySQL <> SQL Server (MS SQL) - remove excess tag.

Comment: Yes I have added "AND Orders.createdAt > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH" this and get the latest 3 months orders but I need to differentiate the orders.
I need to check some product in the orderItems table if exist then need to show the total of that type of orders and without that product orders.

Comment: Please correct your RDBMS tags and choose only one.

Comment: Provide your tables as CREATE TABLE scripts (skip columns non-related to the task), add some sample data as INSERT INTO script, show desired output for this data in table-formatted form.

Comment: I have added the demo content and now could you please help me out?

Comment: how is `staticProductOrder` counted? by title = Static product ?

Comment: we can count the orders with orderItems's table title column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT YEAR(a.createdAt), MONTH(a.createdAt), 
  COUNT(DISTINCT a.OrderID) total_orders, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT b.orderId) static_product_orders
FROM Orders a
LEFT JOIN OrderItems b ON a.OrderID = b.orderId AND b.title = 'Static product'
WHERE a.createdAt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
AND a.shopDomain = 'test.com'
GROUP BY YEAR(a.createdAt), MONTH(a.createdAt)
```

Btw, your tables don't have any index as per your table scripts.

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b20466c7e3c494027c847f027f1c48f7)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MONTH(createdAt), year(createdAt),count(*) as total
FROM Orders 
INNER JOIN OrderItems on Orders.OrderId = OrderItems.orderId 
where Orders.shopDomain = '${Domain}' AND createdAt>= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, 
GETDATE())  group by MONTH(createdAt),year(createdAt);
```

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912173/sql-query-for-getting-data-for-last-3-months/21912827

Comment: You should include all non-aggregated columns to the GROUP BY. In this case the `count(*)`would be calculated based on a month across all years, not per each year. Should be `GROUP BY MONTH(createdAt), year(createdAt)`,